# Format specifier in scanf for bool datatype in C

Tags: c, scanf, format-specifiers

I am using bool datatype in C std99 whose definitions are defined in `<stdbool.h>`. Now I want the user to give me input. What format specifier I must use in scanf to input the boolean value of 1 byte from the user and then manipulate it afterwards in my program.

Comment: Note: scanf() is unsafe. Consider using e.g. strtoXXX() functions.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is none.

Use a temp object as the size of `_Bool` is implementation dependent.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

bool b;
int temp;

scanf("%d", &temp);
b = temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your actual question is not about a specifier for `bool` because there are no "bools" in human languages (which somewhat is most probably your input). Human languages know chars and numbers and more. For those we have format specifiers.

**The actual question is how your bool values show up in your input**:

- Is it 1 or 0?
- TRUE or false?
- yEs or nO?

Depending on your input you need to choose a matching format specifier. And then distinguish between both bool values.

Example for `1` and `0` as bool representation in your input:

```
bool b;
int i;
printf("1/0:\n");
scanf("%d", &i);
if (i) {
  b = 1;
} else {
  b = 0;
}
```

Here an input of `2` would be considered as `1`. Hence if you want a strict implementation then you need to do **error checking/handling** that only `1` or `0` is in your input.

*Disclaimer: **scanf() is unsafe and insecure. Don't use it!** This example is just a demo showing the method of translation input to bool.*

Answer (score -1):

There is no direct way of taking input from users as Boolean . However, we can use a temporary variable and use if-else if statements to take input from users and store that in form of Boolean.

- For this we have to use <string.h> and its built in function strcmp

Here's how it goes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    bool x;
    int temp;
    char y[5];

    printf("Enter Boolean Input True or False: - \n");
    scanf("%s", &y);

    if(strcmp(y, "True") == 0){
        temp = 1;
    }

    else if(strcmp(y, "False") == 0){
        temp = 0;
    }

    x = temp;

    printf("%d", x);

    return 0;
}
```

You can see the output in this image

[image: 1]

Comment: Broken code. It could happen that temp is used without having a value. Every modern compiler should display a warning. Actually using TWO `if` statements is wrong. A boolean value (no tri state) can only have two values. Hence just ONE `if` is required to differentiate between two values. A second `if`is logically redundant.

Comment: In addition your variable `temp` is not required. Simply assign `x` directly.