# rand() returns the same value after the first time

Tags: c

First, here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define NUM_SUITS 4
#define NUM_RANKS 13

bool in_hand[NUM_SUITS][NUM_RANKS] = {false};
bool newcard = {false};
int num_cards, rank, suit, totrank;
const char rank_code[] = {'A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','T','J','Q','K',};
const char suit_code[] = {'C','D','H','S'};

int main_hand ()
{
    suit = rand() % NUM_SUITS;
    rank = rand() % NUM_RANKS;
    if (!in_hand[suit][rank]) {
        in_hand[suit][rank] = true;
        num_cards--;
        if (suit == 0){
            printf("%c of Clubs \n", rank_code[rank]);
        }
        else if (suit == 1){
            printf("%c of Diamonds \n", rank_code[rank]);
        }
        else if (suit == 2){
            printf("%c of Hearts \n", rank_code[rank]);
        }
        else if (suit == 3){
            printf("%c of Spades \n", rank_code[rank]);
       }
    }
}

int print_hand (suit)
{

}

int totrank_check (totrank)
{
    if (totrank > 21) {
        printf ("You lose!");
    }
    else if (totrank == 21) {
        printf ("You win!");
    }
}

int main()
{
     bool stay = {false};
     srand((unsigned) time(NULL));

     totrank = 0;
     num_cards = 2;
     printf("Your hand: ");
     while (num_cards > 0) {
         main_hand();
         totrank = totrank + (rank + 1);
     }
     printf("Total rank: %d\n", totrank);
     totrank_check(totrank);
     printf("\n");
     while (totrank < 24 && stay == false) {
        printf("Another card? 1. Yes 0. No\n");
        scanf("%d", &newcard);
        if(!newcard) {
            main_hand();
        }
        totrank = totrank + (rank + 1);
        totrank_check(totrank);
        printf("Total rank: %d\n", totrank);
        printf("Stay? 1. Yes 0. No\n");
        scanf("%d", &stay);
     }
    return 0;
}
```

Basically it's a code that "simulates" and hand of blackjack.
It starts, `rand()` chooses two numbers, the rank and the suit of the cards, that are set as true in a matrix so that they can't be chosen again in the same combination and then printed. 
There's a check for the total rank of the cards (so that if it exceeds 21 you automatically lose) and then you are asked if you want another card or you want to stay.

Here's the error: if you choose that you want another cards, this new card will be the same as the last one. 
Basically, you get a Ace of Spades, the and Two of Diamonds, then you want another card and you get another Two of Diamonds. And the another, and another. If you remove the rank check in the second while you can see that the rank grows based on the rank of the last card.

Before, the printfs were in that `print_hand()` function, and you could see that you always got the same card, now I moved them in the `main_hand()` function because I thought that it might be the problem (it wasn't) and because having a separate function for the print was redundant. But you can see that technically, the `if(!in_hand[suit][rank])` works, because, since the card is the same, it doesn't enter the if and it doesn't get printed.

I don't know what's causing this problem. Any idea?

Please note I'm already using `srand((unsigned) time(NULL));` to seed `rand()`.

Comment: Your `main_hand` routine picks a random card only once, even if it already has been taken. You need to retry until an untaken is found (crude but it does the job) or maintain an array of 'free' cards out of which you pick.

Comment: Am I not doing that? Once rand() picks the card, there's an if that checks if the suit and the rank are present in an array. If they're not present, they are added, the counter of the cards to give is dimished, and the card picked is printed. If the card is already present, the if doesn't start, the counter is not diminshed, the card is not printed and the while-loop keeps on going until a new card is picked.

Comment: You keep increasing `totrank`, regardless of the result. (I wonder what `totrank` is supposed to represent.)

Comment: totrank is supposed to be the sum of the various rank, since this is supposed to be an hand of blackjack, if your total rank is more than 21 you lose. But you're right, I moved the second increase in the same if where I call main_hand() for the second time, this way it increases only if a different card is drawn.

Comment: I'll go bury myself.

Answer (score 3):

`scanf("%d", &newcard);` and `scanf("%d", &stay);` are a problem as the variables are `bool`, but the format specifier is for `int`.   In 2 places, change like:

```
// scanf("%d", &newcard);
int t;
scanf("%d", &t);
newcard = !!t;
```

3 functions return `int` but do not return anything.  Change to void functions.

```
// int main_hand() {
void main_hand() {
```

There appears to be other logic issues too.
1) Code sometimes exists without knowing if won/loss
2) @Jongware comment above correct:

Lastly: If the same random sequence is still coming up, strip code to a bare `main srand time  printf rand` and see if that works.  `time()`, if not working always returns -1.
Or simple add the following and verify `srand()` called with different values.

```
 int main(void) {
   unsigned now = (unsigned) time(NULL);
   printf("now = %u\n", now);
   srand(now);
```

Comment: I changed the bool variables to int (by the way, what's the correct specifier for bool? I googled and i found %d, that's why I was using it). I also changed the functions from int to void.
Now, I added that part to my code and the problems still presents itself. I noticed that now is always equal to 4201408, even if I launch the program many times. Might that be the problem?
For that logic error, I'm aware, I want to fix it, but I'd like to understand why I can't get more than 2 random numbers first.

Comment: I also answered to @jongware, I think I'm already doing what he's suggesting (unless I'm doing everything wrong, that is).

Comment: @Paul, well at least we know the issue is not a card one, but a `time()` one.  Try `printf("%lld\n", (long long) time());` so we get the entire time.

Comment: @Paul, confident `scanf()` does not have a format specifier for `bool`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920694/format-specifier-in-scanf-for-bool-datatype-in-c

Comment: I added NULL to time() (because I was getting a "too few arguments" error), and what I get is 1418941711 (And it increases slightly between re-runs of the program) while now is the same as before.

Comment: @Paul Your `time(NULL)` is returning a reasonable value - the expected number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970.  Certain code wasn't something like `unsigned now = (unsigned) time;`?  `srand((unsigned) time(NULL));` _should_ be working.  `4201408` looks like a pointer value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67269/discussion-between-chux-and-paul).

Comment: If you're still getting the problem after making the fixes suggested here, then update the code in your past so that others can reproduce