# Is there any format specifier of bool in C?

Tags: c, boolean

In the following example, I'm trying to scan the value of a Boolean type of variable. When I compile in GCC, I get the following warning,

```
warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘_Bool *’ [-Wformat=]
  scanf("%d", &b);
```

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    bool b;

    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("%d\n", b);
}
```

Is there a format specifier of bool in C?

Comment: There isn't one. As an alternative, you might want `printf("%s\n", b ? "true" : "false");`.

Comment: This isn't 100% dupe, since this is about printing and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920694/format-specifier-in-scanf-for-bool-datatype-in-c is about `scanf()`. But still, good enough I guess. :)

Comment: @unwind: You're correct. I'll reopen, with apologies. Now it's time to dig the C standard out.

Comment: I'm not even sure it makes sense for an application to input/output a raw bool, apart from debugging purposes. The bool always stands for something and the user is only interested in whatever that something is. The prompt for user input would be something like "Continue (y/n)?", in which case the input would be characters or whatever. You wouldn't prompt the user "It is assumed you want to continue" after which they would type "true"/"false". Even if you did, it would still not be a bool type used.

Comment: @Lundin: I completely agree. I also go one step further and think that the introduction of bool-stuff into C was a mistake.

Comment: @Bathsheba The main mistake imo was that they didn't drop backwards compatibility and introduced a true boolean type which isn't an `int` in disguise. And then re-make all logical etc operators so that they return a bool type instead of an int (like C++). And then re-make all conditional statements so that they must have a bool type as input. Would have been a monumental improvement of the language in terms of type safety. Billions upon billions of bugs would disappear from C programs by language design. But creating a safe, rational, bug-free language was never a priority of the C committee.

Comment: man microprocessors/microcontrollers actually have addressable boolean registers and arrays of boolean bits.  so it is not a mistake to have a 'bool' type (found in stdbool.h) In general, it is better to not use 'bool' except where it makes sense for the hardware being used.

Comment: Related: *[What is the printf format specifier for bool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307275/what-is-the-printf-format-specifier-for-bool)*. See also [the linked questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/17307275?sort=votes).

Answer (score 6):

There is no format specifier for the `bool` type in C.

For `printf`, you can rely on the implicit promotion to `int`, and use `%d` as the specified formatter.

For `scanf`, you ought to read it into an `int`, and convert appropriately. Again, using `%d`.

Answer (score -6):

There isn't any specifier in C for bool.
You should typecast it in `printf()` to avoid warnings if you want.

But there isn't any dedicated format specifier for representing the **bool** type.

Try the below to avoid the `scanf()` warning:

```
scanf("%d", (int*)&b)
```

Comment: Does `bool` necessarily have the same size as `int`? Otherwise `(int*)&b` looks unsafe to me.

Comment: No its not necessary, generally bool(not everytime) size is 1 byte , this is just for warning only.

Comment: But then `scanf` will store an int-sized value at that location, so the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Then the conversion method will always be there.

Comment: Downvoted for advice to use `scanf("%d",(int*)&b)`, which is clear *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: It may *seem* to work on gcc. That's the nasty thing about [undefined behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/694733). It may not work on next run or after next compilation. Or it may have unrelated side-effects, like corrupting memory somewhere else in the program. Or something else. C standard is very clear that this is illegal usage, but unfortunately the casting disables any possible warnings that compiler could give you. Testing alone is never enough tell if something is legal or not in C.