# Why is my if else statement not showing results of one of the conditions?

Tags: c, boolean

I have been driving myself crazy trying to figure out why the first if statement (if hungry is true or false) will not display the appropriate response. IF you hit true or false it just wont print the statement. I feel like its a silly obvious mistake... but I cant spot it.
----EDIT----

It will not show anything for the first condition/if statement (hungry)
If you put in 1 or 0, it wont display the prinft statement to go along with it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

int main (void){

_Bool hungry = 0;
_Bool thirsty = 0;
_Bool sleepy = 0;


printf("Are you hungry? (1 - true 0 - false) : ");
scanf("%d", &hungry);

printf("Are you thirsty?: ");
scanf("%d", &thirsty);

printf("Are you sleepy?: ");
scanf("%d", &sleepy);


if ( hungry ) {
    printf("Ordering manty \n");
}
     if ( thirsty ) {
        printf("Ordering pot of hot tea \n");
    } 
    else {
        printf("Ordering cup of water \n");
    } 
    if  ( sleepy ) {
        printf("Ordering black coffee \n");
    }
    else {
    printf("Ordering baursaki \n");
    }

}
```

Comment: "will not display the appropriate response". So what does it do exactly? Please describe the *exact* input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: It wont display any response for the first condition (hungry)

Comment: If you put 1 or 0
I commented everything out except for the (hungry) if statement and even then it wont display the printf statement upon entering 1 for true. 
Sorry for lack of explanation.

Comment: *"warning: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'bool *'"* is the warning that your compiler should be giving you.

Comment: It isnt giving that message.

Comment: [can't reproduce](http://ideone.com/Aoicty)

Comment: The other if statements work as they are supposed to. Just not that first one (hungry).

Comment: Only thing that I can think of is perhaps because you are trying to scanf an int but have provided a bool instead. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12920736/3003365

Comment: @MissAnnThropic My guess is that you are somehow not running the correct binary. Because it sounds like your code changes are not being reflected in the result at all. Try adding a new unconditional print in your code to see if that comes out.

Answer (score 2):

This code causes undefined behaviour:

```
_Bool hungry = 0;
scanf("%d", &hungry);
```

The `%d` format specifier requires argument of type `int *`, but you supplied `_Bool *`.  The printf and scanf family do not do any type conversions -- it is up to the programmer to make sure the correct argument type is supplied.

In fact there is no format specifier for `_Bool`. You have to read into another variable and then assign to the bool, e.g.:

```
int temp = 0;
scanf("%d", &temp);
hungry = temp;
```

You might like to check the return value of `scanf`, and perhaps also check `temp` and take action if the input was unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

The `sizeof(_Bool)` is 1, or 1-byte.

By trying to `scanf-%d` into it, you are trying to put 4-bytes into a space only big enough for one byte.  From that point on, you have undefined behavior.

I'd recommend:

```
int temp;             // Temp is 4-bytes. (assuming 32-bit system)
scanf("%d", &temp);   // %d matches 4-byte int.
hungry = !!temp;      // !! converts int value into _Bool value.
```