# Why is scanf working abnormally for bool input in C?

Tags: c, scanf, stdbool

I am trying to get input for 3 bool variables and 1 int variable. Even though I give input correctly, it is not behaving right.

I am using `%d` as format specifier for `bool` in `stdbool.h` as suggested by @taufique in [Format specifier in scanf for bool datatype in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920694/format-specifier-in-scanf-for-bool-datatype-in-c)

Here is my code and its behaviour:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int main( )
{
    bool health,sex,living;
    int age;
    scanf("%d%d%d%d",&sex,&health,&living,&age);
    printf("\n%d %d %d %d\n",sex,health,living,age);
}
```

Console:

```
0 1 0 25
0 0 0 25
```

For some other Input:

```
1 0 0 26
0 0 0 26
```

But when using temporary integer variables to get input as suggested by @ouah in the same [Format specifier in scanf for bool datatype in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920694/format-specifier-in-scanf-for-bool-datatype-in-c) , it works fine.

So why is scanf behaving improperly ?

---

PS : It does work correctly for some input:

```
0 0 1 26
0 0 1 26
```

Comment: Because for `%d` you have to pass an `int*` and nothing else. Passing anything else is undefined behavior. If you're not sure what to pass for each format specifier, check the table here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Comment: It's not scanf, it's your code. taufique's answer is wrong.

Comment: @StoryTeller But it has been approved by many it seems

Comment: You do not know what is behind the bool  object and you cannot assume that it is int.  My advice: less useless forums, more books

Comment: 3 is not many. 3 is users who don't know any better. 20 is many. And did you miss the comment on that answer that explains *exactly* what's wrong with it?

Comment: @StoryTeller Sorry for misleading with that. Is there any way to use scanf to directly get input for bool ?

Comment: @Alagusankar - There is no standard format specifier for booleans. But you don't need one. The extra integer is not going to be the performance bottleneck in your program.

Comment: @StoryTeller Thanks for the mention. I'll better change it to int then.

Comment: FYI, taufique's answer is now deleted. Hopefully no more people will be misled by it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format specifier in scanf for bool datatype in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920694/format-specifier-in-scanf-for-bool-datatype-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

There is no format specifier for `bool` and having one doesn't make much sense. What would the user type, `"true"`? You can't use `%d` for any other type than `int`.

If you for some reason need to take boolean input from stdin, use `int` values `1` or `0`, then convert it to `bool` later. For example:

```
int living; 
scanf("%d", &living);
bool is_living = living;
```

Conversions from `int` to `bool` will automatically convert any non-zero value to `true` and zero to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no format specifier for `bool`.
Because for `bool` it not that clear how it should look like.

There are many possibilities:

- yes/no
- y/n
- true/false
- t/f
- any different case version of the above
- what about locals?
- 1/0

Unlike for numbers and their different formats the above possibilities have different semantics. So support them all with a single specifier is not desirable.

So if you want to support it, you have to chose and implement it by yourself.