# invalid pointer in realloc

Tags: c, pointers, scanf, undefined-behavior, realloc

This error never appeared before, I don't understand why it is happening. I am creating a C program to create an array and then realloc it to add more elements. Im applying many unecessary concepts in the same program to condense some knowledge.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

  // ALWAYS when doing a definition of new elements in a arrays, NEVER use size as a parameter
  // because if you assign one element as one, it will reset the value of size then reseting 
  // size < sizenew.
  // Ex: Do not do:
  //
  // for (size; size < newsize; size++) scanf ("%hu", &size)
  //
  // the number you choose for scanf will affect the number of times the loop will do, because size
  // is a parameter of while 
 

int main()
{
  _Bool decision;
  int* array;
  unsigned short size, newelements, oldsize, add, minus_oldsize, newsize, i, j;

  printf("Hello! put the size of the initial int array!\n");
  scanf("%hu", &size);
  
  array = malloc(size * 4);

  printf("Put the array elements one by one\n");
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) scanf("%d", array + i);

  printf("This is your array:\n");
  for (j = 0; j < size; j++) printf("%d\n", *(array + j));

  printf("Do you want to add more elements? no(0) yes(1)\n");
  scanf("%d", &decision);
  if (decision != 1) return -1;

  printf("How many elements you want to add?\n");
  scanf("%d", &newelements);
  newsize = size + newelements;

  array = realloc(array, newsize * 4);

  free(array);
  
  return 0;
}
```

error:
`realloc(): invalid pointer`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format specifier in scanf for bool datatype in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920694/format-specifier-in-scanf-for-bool-datatype-in-c)

Comment: Turn on the  compiler warnings! There's another gaffe here: `scanf("%d", &newelements);` but you have `unsigned short newelements`

Comment: `scanf("%d", &decision);` is undefined behaviour as `%d` requires a pointer to `int` but you have given it a pointer to `_Bool`. They are different types with possibly different sizes.

Comment: Don't use "shrivelled" variables just because you don't need the range of `int`, without a good reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem is this call of `scanf` for an object of the type `_Bool`

```
_Bool decision;

//...

scanf("%d", &decision);
```

Unfortunately there is no conversion specifier for objects of the type `_Bool` that can be safely used in a call of `scanf`.

Instead you could use an object of the type `int`.

Another problem is using an incorrect conversion specifier in this call

```
scanf("%d", &newelements);
```

It seems you mean

```
scanf("%hu", &newelements);
```