# Why do I get an error when I use %d in scanf when I use stdbool.h?

Tags: c, visual-studio, stdbool

There are times when I use stdbool.h while practicing coding. At this time, if the format modifier of scanf is given as %d, the following error message occurs.

> c:\project\hello\hello\hello.c(11): warning C4477: 'scanf' : format string '%d' requires an argument of type 'int *' but variadic argument 3 has type 'bool'

It seems to compile, but it doesn't seem to properly recognize true/false or 0/1 inputs at runtime. I wonder if there's something I'm missing out on.

Comment: Please post the code in question; it's much easier to understand than descriptions of code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920694/format-specifier-in-scanf-for-bool-datatype-in-c

Comment: It's a warning not an error (which explains why it compiles) and it makes it pretty clear what the problem is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a `bool` (or `_Bool`) to `scanf`. When using `%d`, you should pass the address of an `int`.

If your `bool` is named `x`, then use:

```
int temporary;
if (1 != scanf("%d", &temporary))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error, scanf did not work as expected.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
x = temporary;
```

(For `exit`, insert `#include <stdlib.h>` in your source code.)